# Pytesseract skipping numbers while detecting text

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I wrote a simple python code to get text from an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfcHb.jpg). Most of the text here is Hindi but only text I care about is the 12 digit number in the image "5485 5000 8000".
Here is the code I wrote:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('Aadhar-Card.jpg',0)
text = pytesseract.image_to_data(img,lang='eng', config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
print(text)
h, w = img.shape
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img) 
for b in boxes.splitlines():
    b = b.split(' ')
    img1 = cv2.rectangle(img, (int(b[1]), h - int(b[2])), (int(b[3]), h - int(b[4])), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sPyk.png).
So the number is the only thing getting skipped. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may crop the interested section (the number area) at first, then implement the OCR.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('Aadhar-Card.jpg',0)
crop_img = img[173:173+30, 117:117+150]
strNum = pytesseract.image_to_string(crop_img, config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
print(strNum)
cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Is there any way I can decide the cropping coordinates based on the image? Like if I want to retrieve a 12 digit number of the same format in another image where it's position might be different?

Comment: In that case, we want to detect the number area at first. One way is to use the [template matching feature in cv2](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) to get coordinates of the 0 1 2...9 samples (you manually prepared these 10 images beforehand), which in combine would strongly indicate the cropping coordinates.

Comment: Ah okay. But I still don't quite understand how to go about doing it (template matching) with photos of individual digits.

Comment: You can reuse the code in the [Mario case](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html#template-matching-with-multiple-objects). Instead of gold coin, you would search the individual digit, from 0, 1, 2, to 9, separately, which are ten times of searching operation in total. After this, you would have collected 12 (or less if there were missed cases) rectangles. You can then pick out the four extreme coordinates of those 12 rectangles (pick 4 out of 48): the most topleft /bottomleft /topright /bottomright ones.

Comment: Okay this looks very promising. Thanks a lot for the help!